# Virtual PC on XP

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-pc

Is there a version of Virtual PC 6 that i can run on XP? And where can i download it from?

Like thisone: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx, but this is only for windows 7.

Comment: This should have been asked at SU, not at SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Virtual Box or VMWare.

Virtual Box is free, you can download it from: http://www.virtualbox.org/

Answer (score 2):

It's available on [Microsoft's website](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04d26402-3199-48a3-afa2-2dc0b40a73b6&displaylang=en)

[This site](http://www.oldversion.com/Virtual_PC.html) has an archived version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a version of Virtual PC 6 which runs on XP, although it looks like it was removed from microsoft.com download area. But you can still try to download it from [here](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Microsoft-Virtual-PC-Download-8335.html).